# It prints The printf statement twice

Tags: c

This is really strange it prints this line `printf("Do you want to continue Yes (Y) or No (N): \n");` Not using any loop nothing but still it prints that statement twice

```
int main()
{

int led=0;
int ohm=0;
char check;
int flag=0;

while (led < 1 || led > 3){
    printf("Enter the number of switch you want to close: \n\n");
    printf("  ********************     Press 1 for switch (LED) 1     ********************\n");
    printf("  ********************     Press 2 for switch (LED) 2     ********************\n");
    printf("  ********************     Press 3 for switch (LED) 3     ********************\n");

    printf("Switch: ");
    scanf("%d", &led);
}

printf("\n\n");
while (ohm < 1 || ohm > 3){
    printf("Enter the resistance of Rheostat: \n\n");
    printf("  ********************     Press 1 for 10 ohm resistance  ********************\n");
    printf("  ********************     Press 2 for 20 ohm resistance  ********************\n");
    printf("  ********************     Press 3 for 30 ohm resistance  ********************\n");

    printf("Resistance: ");
    scanf("%d", &ohm);
}


    while (flag == 0)
    {
        //LED-1
        if(led== 1 && ohm== 1 )
        {
            printf("LED-1 is blinking 2 times\n");
        }

        if(led== 1  && ohm== 2)
        {
            printf("LED-1 is blinking 4 times\n");
        }

        if(led== 1  && ohm== 3 )
        {
            printf("LED-1 is blinking 6 times\n");
        }

        //LED-2
        if(led== 2  && ohm== 1 )
        {
            printf("LED-2 is blinking 2 times\n");
        }

        if(led== 2  && ohm== 2 )
        {
            printf("LED-2 is blinking 4 times\n");
        }

        if(led == 2  && ohm == 3)
        {
            printf("LED-2 is blinking 6 times\n");
        }

        //LED-3
        if(led == 3  && ohm == 1 )
        {
            printf("LED-3 is blinking 2 times\n");
        }

        if(led == 3  && ohm == 2)
        {
            printf("LED-3 is blinking 4 times\n");
        }

        if(led == 3 && ohm == 3)
        {
            printf("LED-3 is blinking 6 times\n");
        }

        led = 0;
        ohm = 0;
        printf("Do you want to continue Yes (Y) or No (N): \n");
        scanf("%c", &check);

        if(check =='Y' || check =='y')
        {

            while (led < 1 || led > 3){
            printf("Enter the number of switch you want to close on: ");
            scanf("%d", &led);
            }

            while (ohm < 1 || ohm > 3){
            printf("Enter the resistance of Rheostat: ");
            scanf("%d", &ohm);
            }
        }

        if(check=='N' || check=='n')
        {
            printf("Thanks for using the program");
            flag = 1;
        }



    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "Not using any loop" - there are several loops in your code...

Comment: Looks familiar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917029/run-time-check-failure-2-stack-around-the-variable-check-was-corrupted I meant it when I said to avoid using `scanf`.

Comment: Someone needs to read up about `else`.  And functions. And not using their output string as the first arg to `printf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scanf(" %d", &led); , scanf(" %c", &check); etc. in the code.
Adding an extra space before the format specifier will solve the problems caused by garbage/newline in the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

The first time `scanf("%c", &check);` finds some garbage (that does not match `y` or `n`) so your program can do another loop.

As someone else already noticed, that garbage might be the newline after the ohm input.

Some ideas to solve the problem:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t436518-get-rid-of-trailing-newline-for-scanf.html

> ```
> scanf(" %c", &input);
> ```
>
> (leading space will eat whitespace in the input)

[scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer)

Comment: Probably the newline character after the `scanf("%d", &ohm);`

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", &ohm);
```

Here when you input a number and press ENTER, the number is processed by `scanf`, but the newline is still in the input buffer, then later

```
printf("Do you want to continue Yes (Y) or No (N): \n");
scanf("%c", &check);
```

`check` will actually store the newline, not `'N'`,

```
if(check=='N' || check=='n')
{
    printf("Thanks for using the program");
    flag = 1;
}
```

so `flag` will not be set to `1`, the `while` loop will continue again. In the second loop, `check` can be assigned `'N'`, the loop will terminate after.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `scanf("%c ", &check);`. Notice the extra space given after `%c` which will absorb extra new line character.

Answer (score 0):

use `getchar` and it works just fine, you can try it [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php)

Comment: Then suggest using two `getchar` together to avoid the same issue.